# How to find the inverse of a 3x3 MDS matrix

Tags: aes, block-cipher, mds

I implemented a block cipher similar to AES.
But the reason I can't decrypt is that I can't get the inverse MDS matrix.
The MDS matrix I used is a 3x3 MDS matrix on $GF(2^8) \implies GF(2^8)$ like AES

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 &2 \\
2 & 2 & 1\\
2 & 1 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}

The encryption process is the same as that of AES mixcolumns, and the MDS matrix used is as above.

I need the MDS inverse matrix required for decryption. 
What is the inverse of this MDS matrix on $GF(2^8)$?

I searched for Euclid-Wallis Algorithm or extended euclidean algorithm but I did not understand it well.

- How can I find the inverse of a 3x3 MDS matrix?

Answer (score 3):

Your matrix contains 2 which is not an element of $\operatorname{GF}(2^8)$ unless it means $x$. In this case, we can use SageMath to find the inverse as

```
R.<x> = PolynomialRing(GF(2), 'x')
S.<y> = QuotientRing(R, R.ideal(x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1))
S.is_field()
S.cardinality()
y^8 + y^4 + y^3 + y + 1

A = matrix(S,[[1,y,y],[y,y,1],[y,1,y],])
A.inverse()
```

That produces this output

```
True
256
0

[                                  1 y^7 + y^6 + y^5 + y^4 + y^2 + y + 1 y^7 + y^6 + y^5 + y^4 + y^2 + y + 1]
[y^7 + y^6 + y^5 + y^4 + y^2 + y + 1 y^7 + y^6 + y^5 + y^4 + y^2 + y + 1                                   1]
[y^7 + y^6 + y^5 + y^4 + y^2 + y + 1                                   1 y^7 + y^6 + y^5 + y^4 + y^2 + y + 1]
```

The matrix written in standard binary representation is:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
  00000001 & 11110111 & 11110111 \\
  11110111 & 11110111 & 00000001 \\
  11110111 & 00000001 & 11110111
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I think $2$ in his matrix might mean $x$ since $2=(10)_2$ in binary (and the field $GF(2^8)$ can be constructed directly with `R.<x> = GF(2^8, modulus=x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1)`).

Comment: @corpsfini yes, $2 = (10)_2$, my mistake. thanks. Corrected. Yes, that is the direct one hiding the details.

Comment: That's not correct; multiplying the original matrix with the supposed inverse doesn't yield the identity matrix; look at the dot product of the original third row with the inverse's third column.

Comment: Thanks to poncho for noticing the mistake. The matrix is not correctly transferred into sageMath. Now it should be correct.

Comment: How does SageMath compute the result?

Comment: @StackDanny are you asking the math behind it?

Comment: Yes, @kelalaka.

Comment: @StackDanny One need to look at the source to see the exact algorithm, however, you can [call them in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70524232/1820553) if you want. You may ask at ask.sagemath for more details.

Comment: I was able to figure it out, I posted my findings as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to compute this result.

- I followed the steps on the answer on [how to invert a matrix in modular arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/86367/374413).
- All operations are replaced with their $GF(2^8)$ counterpart as described by [this answer on "calculating the inverse of a polynomial"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/48923/104623).

---

I want to show the C++ code I was able to write with these two answers. With the code we can invert any `N` sized matrix in the $GF(2^8)$ field. [The full code can be found here](https://godbolt.org/z/r6a66rozG).

These are the galois operations as shown by Thomas Pornin:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

namespace galois {
    constexpr int add(int x, int y) {
        return x ^ y;
    }

    constexpr int mul(int x, int y) {
        int z = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
            z ^= x & -(y & 1);
            y >>= 1;
            x <<= 1;
            x ^= (0x11B & -(x >> 8));
        }
        return z;
    }

    constexpr int inverse(int x) {
        int z = x;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
            z = galois::mul(z, z);
            z = galois::mul(z, x);
        }
        return galois::mul(z, z);
    }

    constexpr int divide(int x, int y) {
        return mul(x, inverse(y));
    }
}
```

And this is the `matrix_inverse` as described by Jyrki Lahtonen, but with using the galois operations:

```
template<std::size_t N>
using matrix = std::array<std::array<int, N>, N>;

template<std::size_t N>
matrix<N> matrix_inverse(matrix<N> M) {

    matrix<N> R{}; //fills R with 0s
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        R[i][i] = 1; //makes the matrix the identity matrix
    }
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i) {

        //sets M[i][i] to 1, divide by row by inverse
        auto diagonal = M[i][i];
        auto inv = galois::inverse(diagonal);
        for (unsigned row = 0; row < N; ++row) {
            M[i][row] = galois::mul(inv, M[i][row]);
            R[i][row] = galois::mul(inv, R[i][row]);
        }

        //pivots the column
        for (unsigned col = 0; col < N; ++col) {
            if (col == i) continue;

            auto n = M[col][i];
            for (unsigned row = 0; row < N; ++row) {
                M[col][row] = galois::add(galois::mul(n, M[i][row]), M[col][row]);
                R[col][row] = galois::add(galois::mul(n, R[i][row]), R[col][row]);
            }
        }
    }
    return R;
}
```

And this is how we can call `matrix_inverse` to test the result:

```
template<std::size_t N>
void print_matrix(matrix<N> m) {
    for (auto& i : m) {
        for (auto& i : i) {
            std::cout << i << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
int main() {
    matrix<3> m = 
    { {
        {1, 2, 2},
        {2, 2, 1},
        {2, 1, 2},
    } };

    std::cout << "Input -\n";
    print_matrix(m);

    matrix<3> inverse = matrix_inverse(m);

    std::cout << "\nInverse -\n";
    print_matrix(inverse);
}
```

As can be seen in the output, we calculated the correct inverse of your matrix:

```
Input -
1 2 2
2 2 1
2 1 2

Inverse -
1 247 247
247 247 1
247 1 247
```

---

As a second test, we can replicate the correct AES decryption MixColumns matrix:

```
matrix<4> m =
{ {
    {2, 3, 1, 1},
    {1, 2, 3, 1},
    {1, 1, 2, 3},
    {3, 1, 1, 2},
} };

matrix<4> inverse = matrix_inverse(m);

std::cout << "Inverse -\n";
print_matrix(inverse);
```

Output:

```
Inverse -
14 11 13 9
9 14 11 13
13 9 14 11
11 13 9 14
```